# Is there a word for "less blunt"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a good word for *less blunt*. In a conversation, I had today a lady who was speaking to me in a very blunt and insensitive way, and I want to express how I’d appreciate if she were less blunt.

Comment: I recommend getting a thesaurus and looking for antonyms, which would help show research and why the items you initially found don't work. Incidentally, your question made me realize that, depending on its use, either *soft* or *sharp* can be antonyms of *blunt*.

Comment: How are you defining a "good" word? What's wrong with simply asking her to be "less blunt"? (Explaining that might help choose the right way to express a request.)

Comment: “Sharper” is a single word for less blunt, but isn’t what the OP is looking for.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because although the title suggests a straightforward English Language question, its specific context makes it a question on social intercourse, which is not the remit of this SE. (The single answer so far is, indeed, cast accordingly.)

Comment: You can be rude and direct, or rude in a subtle way, so it's not clear what is required - do you want her to coat her rudeness in fine language, or to actually be nice, polite, optimistic, encouraging, sweet, and helpful?

Comment: More compassionate; less forthright.

Answer (score 3):

One antonym for the words *less blunt* could be *more diplomatic*.

Diplomacy is the gentle art of persuasion. There are times, of course, when like Teddy Roosevelt we need to carry a big stick. Out of respect for people, however, we will often have a better outcome when we speak softly, reserving the big stick for egregious violations.

The apostle Paul in his letter to the Christians at Ephesus, encouraged them to "speak the truth in love" (Ephesians 4:15). Speaking the truth in love is a mark of spiritual maturity, and the person who controls their tongue is wise.

Jesus's half-brother James encouraged his readers to be:

- quick to hear,
- slow to speak, and
- slow to anger

To be slow to speak does not mean to talk slowly. It does mean to think before speaking. It means putting one's mind in gear before putting the mouth in gear.

The blunt speaker you speak of needs to be schooled in the art of diplomacy. When dealing with an angry and blunt talker, the following proverb is apt:

> A gentle answer turns away wrath, but a harsh word stirs up anger (Proverbs 15:1 NIV).

Being blunt with a blunt speaker is generally not a good idea. When the blunt talker raises their voice, the diplomatic listener lowers their voice and speaks the truth in love.

Comment: Your answer also suggests "gentle" as an antonym of "blunt" in this context.  Also, the King James Version calls it "a _soft_ answer", and "soft" has been suggested by other commenters.

Comment: @DougWarren: Good points, Doug! Don

Answer (score 2):

Tactful or sharp are good words to use instead of “less Blunt” but it depends on how you’re using it.